# How to create an empty slide object?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am just trying to make an empty slide object by doing this -

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide empty_slide = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide();
```

The error is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the
 COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493445-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263
B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception f
rom HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOn
ly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Bo
olean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipChec
kThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean s
kipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Program.GetBulletPointTransition(Application PowerPoint_App, Presentation
presentation) in c:\Users\PEAK\Documents\Peak Sourcing\Work\ppt_test\ppt_test\Pr
ogram.cs:line 539
   at Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\PEAK\Documents\Peak Sourcing\Work\
ppt_test\ppt_test\Program.cs:line 79
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: why are you setting it to null? null is different from empty slide! what is the error?

Comment: It is saying something like 'not set to an instance of an object'. Okay, what should I set it to?

Comment: `var empty_slide = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide();`

Comment: Null is the absence of an object, not a substitute for an empty one (although they are unfortunately used like that sometimes).

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: And what is the error in the first line of code? Before you set `emptySlide` to null.

Comment: Please see the updated text.

Answer (score 1):

HERE'S THE CORRECT ANSWER:

You should not directly create new instances of class Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide. Instead, use code like the following:

```
        Presentation ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open(pptPath, WithWindow: MsoTriState.msoFalse);
        int newSlideNumber = (ppt.Slides.Count + 1);
        var slide = ppt.Slides.Add(newSlideNumber, PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly);
        slide.Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "hello!";
```

NOTE: In case you checked the relevant forums for available answers to your question, you should NOT change the project's build settings to use platform target of x86.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `empty_slide = null;` part from your first code. That should do it.
Use the following -

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide empty_slide = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide();
```

Comment: Please see the updated code. It still gives an error